# heroku .rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/heroku: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I was getting issues with the Heroku CLI although it was updated, so I was told to make sure Heroku isn't running in two places and that the local version is updated.

If I type:

```
which heroku
```

I get

```
/usr/local/bin/heroku
```

But if I try to run heroku log or any heroku command I get:

```
-bash: /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/heroku: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, etc. How do I approach this?

Comment: It'll help if you say which OS you are using, as well as how you installed RVM.

Comment: I'm using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.8 and I have RVM version 2.0